# ImportError: No module named PIL - Error after successful install

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I got Sublime Text Editor 3.2.2 and Python 3.8, in my MacOS Terminal I input:

`pip Install pillow`....which was successful (I checked with Pip Freeze), then in my code:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
```

Then when I run the program I get:

```
ImportError: No module named PIL
[Finished in 0.6s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/michaelessey/Desktop/Python/Python Projects/TKinter Course/Icon_images.py"]
[dir: /Users/michaelessey/Desktop/Python/Python Projects/TKinter Course]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Does anyone know the issue here, please?

Comment: This sounds like a notorious environment issue. Whatever virtual environment the script is running in, is not the environment you installed the package into.

Comment: You can always check what packages you have installed with `pip list`

Comment: What directory were you in when you installed it?

Comment: So you installed the `pillow` in your default environment, but you `import pillow` from anaconda environment. My suggestion is first to activate conda `conda activate`, then install pillow to the conda `conda install -c anaconda pillow`